# Retrieve nearby places of a current location

Tags: android, google-places-api

I am working on an application where I need to retrieve nearby restaurants of a current location. Forums suggested me to use Google Places API. 
When I read about Google Place API, it says that a project needs to be a "Google App Engine project" + Android client. But I got confused that will that be a right way of doing it as I am fairly new to Google world.

Can someone suggest me which will be the best way of retrieving nearby restaurants of a current location?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

follow this link.
Create an app key for your app & You only have to make an Http request, & you will get all info in Xml//json.
https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/xml?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&types=food&name=harbour&sensor=false&key=AddYourOwnKeyHere

In above url, Add your Api key & locaton. It will return a xml to you containing all restras in circle of 500m.

this url will only accept get Requests. Yov will have to append all parameters in Url itself.

```
@Override
                public void run() 
                {
                     String params="location="+(location.getLatitude())+","+(location.getLongitude())+"&radius=5000&types=food&sensor=false&key=your kay";
                        try
                        {
                            http.getPlaces(new URL("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/xml?"+params));
                            Log.i("url", "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/xml?"+params);
                            setList();
                        } 
                        catch (MalformedURLException e)
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        catch (Exception e) 
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                }
            });


public void getPlacesDetails(URL url) throws Exception {
    try 
    {
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setUseCaches(false);

        connection.setConnectTimeout(TIMEOUT_CONNECT_MILLIS);
        connection.setReadTimeout(TIMEOUT_READ_MILLIS);
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");

        inStream = (InputStream) connection.getInputStream();


        SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
        XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();

        HospitalDetailParser myXMLHandler = new HospitalDetailParser();
        xr.setContentHandler(myXMLHandler);
        xr.parse(new InputSource(inStream));


    }

    catch (MalformedURLException e) 
    {

        Log.i("exception in sms", "" + e.toString());
        throw e;
    }

    catch (Exception e) 
    {

        Log.i("exception in sms", "" + e.toString());
        throw e;
    }

}
```

Comment: There's also a "getting started" guide to the Places API at: https://developers.google.com/academy/apis/maps/places/

Comment: On using Google Places API, I am getting a "VerifyError" at runtime. LogCat says - "Could not find GenericUrl class" but compilation shows no such error. I searched on the forums and implemented all the suggested solutions but still getting the same error... What am I missing?

Comment: can you provide the relevent code & log.
i have edited the answer. Please check.

Comment: Log - 07-19 12:22:40.438: D/dalvikvm(543): Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
07-19 12:22:41.109: E/dalvikvm(543): Could not find class 'com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpTransport', referenced from method com.test.api.GoogleAPIActivity.<clinit> 07-19 12:22:41.168: E/AndroidRuntime(543): java.lang.VerifyError: com/test/api/GoogleAPIActivity

Comment: Code-private static final HttpTransport transport = new ApacheHttpTransport();public void performSearch() throws Exception {
try {HttpRequestFactory httpRequestFactory = createRequestFactory(transport);
HttpRequest request = httpRequestFactory.buildGetRequest(new GenericUrl(PLACES_SEARCH_URL));
request.getUrl().put("location", latitude + "," + longitude);
request.getUrl().put("radius", 500);
request.getUrl().put("sensor", "false");
   
}PlacesList places = request.execute().parseAs(PlacesList.class);
for (Place place : places.results) {    System.out.println(place);
    }

Comment: I did using following code: public JSONObject executeHttpGet(String uri) throws Exception{
     HttpGet req = new HttpGet(uri);
     HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
     
     HttpResponse resLogin = client.execute(req);
     BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(resLogin.getEntity().getContent()));
     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
     String s = null;
     while ((s = r.readLine()) != null) {
         sb.append(s);
 }
     json = sb.toString();
     jObj = new JSONObject(json);
  return jObj;
 }